# Manually localise in RTAB-Map

Tags: ros-kinetic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there some way to manually localize on RTAB-Map?

At the moment, when we launch RTAB-Map in localization mode, we need to drive the rover account for a bit until it finds enough visual points to localize.

Is there some way to manually localize on the map so we don't have to wait (an undetermined amount of time) for the rover to figure out where it is on the map?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318331/manually-localise-in-rtab-map/) by [Drkstr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29909/drkstr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2019-03-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

yes it is possible to drop a "guess" with RVIZ using the "[2D Pose Estimate](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack#A2D_Pose_Estimate)" button like in this [video](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack) at 0:50. Make sure to remap the topic `initialpose` of rtabmap node and that the Fixed Frame in global options is `map`. Example (if rtabmap is started in rtabmap namespace):
[image: image description]

cheers,
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2019-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Drkstr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29909/drkstr/) on 2019-03-25**:
Awesome, thanks.